# ASP.NET AJAX Animation work fine in Localhost but not work in ip host

Tags: asp.net

if I run it on my machine using `localhost:56993/WebSite7/Default.aspx` it works fine

if I run it using `192.168.1.3/WebSite7/Default.aspx` as an address the page opens but when click I click on the textbox no fadein happens:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %> <%@ Register
assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI"
tagprefix="asp" %> <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>


</head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>



        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:AnimationExtender ID="Button1_AnimationExtender" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1"  >
               <Animations>
    <OnClick>
    <Sequence>
    <StyleAction Attribute="display" Value="block" AnimationTarget="Panel1" />
    <Parallel Duration="1" AnimationTarget="Panel1" Fps="20">
     <FadeIn />
     </Parallel>
     </Sequence>
    </OnClick>   </Animations>

        </asp:AnimationExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" 


            style="position:absolute; top: 180px; left: 89px; height: 148px; width: 151px; ">
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="Shortest" 
                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="99px" 
                ShowGridLines="True" Width="61px" >
                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
                <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" />
                <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" 
                    ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            </asp:Calendar>
        </asp:Panel>

        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form> </body> </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? It appears as if I am in the same situation. I am also using ToolScriptManager. Besides this I have a ComboBox and Update panel which work fine on localhost but not on my web host.